# O que é um é backoff exponencial?

Tags: design-pattern

- O que é?
- Pra que serve?
- Em quais situações da pra usa-lo?
- Existe apenas uma estratégia ou várias? (*Exemplo:* Fibonacci backoff)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É uma estratégia onde cada tentativa ou iteração de um procedimento é seguida de um intervalo, cada vez maior (opcionalmente até um limite fixo) em caso de falha ou necessidade de ajuste de fluxo. O Feedback é uma característica (seja ele vindo da própria iteração anterior, ou de medidas feitas durante o procedimento)

Geralmente serve para evitar congestão de rede, sobrecargas ou consumo desnecessário de recursos, afinal, se houve uma falha mais que uma vez seguida em determinado intervalo, geralmente não adianta ficar insistindo da mesma maneira.

Deve usar em toda situação em que repetidas ações descontroladas geram consumo de recurso ou ineficiência.

Clássico é o próprio protocolo Ethernet, usado em praticamente qualquer rede moderna de dados.

Outro cenário é por exemplo uma conexão UDP, onde você vai limitando os pacotes até que fiquem compatíveis com sua banda de saída e a recepção do outro lado (ainda é um cenário de "falha", mas que faz parte natural do protocolo de ajuste).

Mais um cenário exemplo (menos comum o uso do termo, mas mesmo princípio) é o consumo de uma API de um servidor, em caso de falha ou sistema ocupado. Se duas requisições seguidas não atingiram o objetivo, tenta-se um intervalo maior entre as próximas.

Tem estratégias mais comuns, como simplesmente ir multiplicando o intervalo anterior por um fator (afinal é exponencial) mas nada impede de você criar a sua própria.

Ainda, em se tratando de Ethernet, estes dois algoritmos são comuns:

- Binary exponential backoff
- Truncated binary exponential backoff

(Esse segundo é quase igual o anterior, mas com aquele limite máximo que eu comentei de intervalo)

Leitura relacionada:

> [Exponential Backoff <sup>(en)</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff)
> [Network Congestion Avoidance <sup>(en)</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_congestion#Avoidance)
> [Teoria de controle](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_de_controle)